# C# How to disable paint event of a panel when called using panel.BringToFront() method?

Tags: c#

I have two Panels stacked in Form, When one panel1 is showing,the panel2 is in background and If i call Panel2 using BringToFront() method to View the Panel2, The paint Event of the Panel2 is calling. So i want to prevent Panel2 from calling Paint Event to Disable Redrawing of the Panel.

Comment: Have you tried achieving this through Panel1.Visible = false; instead? just my 2 cents, thanks!

Comment: i tried with visible property also and it is the calling paint method.

Comment: There are number of images in both panels, So if i swap between panels it is flickering even though i enabled double buffering in my Form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the paint method is a default event that has any regard to "display", hmm have you tried doing a workaround like creating a separate static flag for the purpose of preventing your paint events?

(again this is just a workaround)

Sample :

```
public bool displayed {get; set;}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   displayed = false;
}    

private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if(!displayed) {
         // do paint functions
         displayed = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT : Please try this one.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.Green, 3),
                new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50));
            //Drawing an ellipse
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(60, 60, 100, 100));
            //Drawing text
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", new Font("Verdana", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Green), 200, 200);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }

        // code described below
        public class MyDisplay : Panel
        {
            public MyDisplay()
            {
                this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            }
        }
```

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered(v=vs.110).aspx) *Gets or sets a value indicating whether this control should redraw its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker.* This should now work regardless if SendToBack() BringToFront() or Visible set.

Comment: Have you tried this ?

Comment: would you mind sharing your form load and paint code? I'll try to polish this in my environment.

Comment: Please try with simple code as you can. I simply want to prevent repaint of my control once loaded.

Comment: hi, please see my edit, hopefully this works

Comment: then something is wrong with your code...that I cannot prove as I don't see it, in my solution, no flickering happens and the hide & show panel works without issue.